# Bypass shipping options for downloadable products

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

I am building a store that sells books, but also offers subscriptions and downloads.

Currently I have the shipping calculated after the user enters their address.  Once the address is entered, the user advanced to the next page with shipping options.

I would like for people who purchase non-shippable items to bypass that page.

Any Idea on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have already set up some shipping rules, and marked digital products as "free shipping", then Store will automatically calculate the shipping cost at $0 for orders which contain only items with free shipping enabled. If you have set up a "default shipping method", then all other orders will already have an estimated shipping cost using the default method when customers land on the shipping page.

You can use this fact to redirect customers past the shipping page when shipping has been calculated at $0. For example, in your shipping page template, use the following code:

```
{if order_shipping_val == 0}
    {redirect="checkout/continue"}
{/if}
```